# Study the convergence of the series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

So I don't know how to apply Cauchy's Criterion to study the convergence of series.

I know that $|{{e^{i\pi/n}}}| = 1$ so  $|\frac{{e^{i\pi/n}}}{\sqrt{n}}| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\;    \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. I got this far but I don't know if I'm making a mistake:

let $ m,n,N \in \mathbb{N} : N \geq n \geq m : $

$|\sum_{n=m}^{N} \frac{e^{\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}}| \leq \sum_{n=m}^{N} |\frac{e^{\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}}| = \sum_{n=m}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Now, since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ decreases as n increases, my reasoning is that for every $\epsilon > 0\;$ I can find a high enough m such that $\sum_{n=m}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon \;$ and by extension $\sum_{n=m}^{N} |\frac{e^{\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}}| < \epsilon$.

My confusion comes when trying to think of how to pick N, does the Cauchy criterion have to work for every single natural number greater than m? Because in that case, this line of thought would not be helpful since the infinite series $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ does not converge, so either the original series in question does not converge, or the way I obtained the upper bound is not helpful.

Also, I wanted to add that I know that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}} = 0 $, but I know that this condition is necessary but not sufficient for the series to be convergent. If proving this series convergence is not best done by the Cauchy Criterion, in what other way should I proceed? And if I am making a mistake in my reasoning, would you be kind enough to point where the flaws are? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your upper bound is not helpful. Then again, Cauchy is not terribly helpful here either.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{i\pi/n}-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges (even absolutely).

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges.  For fixed x, the tail of your series looks divergent.

Comment: Well, I think it's a good idea to study the convergence of the series $\sum \frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\sum \frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that
$$
e^{i\pi/n} = \cos(\pi/n)+i\sin(\pi/n)
$$
and hence for each $N$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{e^{i\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sqrt n} + i\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{\sqrt n}.
$$
A sequence of complex numbers converges if and only if both the real and imaginary parts converge, and from $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(\pi/n)=1$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{\sqrt n}=+\infty$ that the real part of the series does not converge, and hence the series does not converge.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for your answer! Sorry if I'm too dense, I'm very rusty at this, but how do I connect those 2 limits to affirm that the real part diverges? I was thinking of looking for a divergent minorand and use the comparison test, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{cos{\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}} $, so that wouldn't work here, could you explain why those two arguments imply that the real part is divergent?

Comment: @ELC Apply the limit comparison test to $a_n=\frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sqrt n}$ and $b_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: You may use the fact that $\cos x$ is decreasing and positive on $[0,\pi/2).$ Therefore $$\cos(\pi/n)\ge {1\over 2}, \ \ n\ge 3 $$ Hence $$\sum_{n=3}^N{\cos(\pi/n)\over \sqrt{n}}\ge {1\over 2}\sum_{n=3}^N{1\over \sqrt{n}}$$